# Image stop being responsive as a child of a <a> element

Tags: image, responsive, amp-html

I am trying to make the logo to redirect to the homepage, but when I put the image in an anchor its responsiveness doesn't work. I am using the "Simple Blog" template from here https://www.ampstart.com/templates

```
<a href="/">
  <amp-img src="/images/logo/logo.svg" width="435" height="61.3" layout="fixed" class="my0 mx-auto " alt="Logo"></amp-img>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the layout type of amp-img from `fixed` to `responsive`.

I seem to recall possibly having some issues with SVG and responsive, but I could be thinking of something else. If `responsive` doesn't work try `intrinsic`.

See the tips and tricks section of the [amp-img page](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-img) for more info.